# Call C functions from R without writing C code

Tags: r, c

I've found several ways to call C code from R: .C, .Call, Rcpp. But they all seem to require to write and compile some C code.

In Python, it is possible to call functions from a C library without writing C code with something that look like this:

```py
import ctypes
mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
mylib.myfunction.argtypes = [
        ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]
mylib.myfunction.restype = ctypes.c_int
i = ctypes.c_int()
res = mylib.myfunction(ctypes.POINTER(i))
print(res)
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in R?

Comment: I don't think so, no. It's often seen as a disadvantage (as other languages do support direct interfaces like you've identified), but it is what it is afaict. I look forward to others telling me I'm missing something :-)